# asp.net referencing css on Markup page issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I would like to reference a CSS on the markup page like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
```

It works perfectly on local machine but if I publish it to IIS, the fancybox wasn't showing, when I check the link of the source, it would become `developement.server.com/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4` instead of `developement.server.com/applicationName/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4` (Missing the "alias")

I've also tried changing it to below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
```

But the link will be `developement.server.com/applicationName/templates/~/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4`

I've also tried using "<%#%> to reference the path like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4")%>" media="screen" />
```

But there will be an error on the development tools saying "$ is not defined", I guess it's because the css is later than the javascript function..

The correct path should be `developement.server.com/applicationName/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4`

How can I reference the css link correctly ? Or are there any IIS settings which allows the user to reference relative path?

Comment: If you want to add "~" to reference the local path, your element needs to include runat="server".

Comment: just now tried adding runat="server" but the link was still the same... (developement.server.com/applicationName/templates/~/Script/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4)